# Disable deploy on build visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Every time I rebuild my project, Visual Studio automatically deploy it to server through FTP. How can I disable it?

Comment: What type of project is it?

Comment: Web project using MVC3

Comment: Do you use MSBuild for building your project?

Comment: I'm using MS Web Deploy

Comment: Check if you have some post build actions? Is not a built in feature.

Comment: No, I don't install any post build action. I just set up a deploy profile and deploy my website once. Now every time I rebuild my project, it automatically deploy

Comment: Take a look at the answers for this question: [How to automatically publish a website on build in Visual Studio 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2262478/674700). Have you implemented any of the solutions suggested in the answers?

Comment: No, I'm not. Just publish my project once via Web Deploy